# How is damage, CP and IV related?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm getting a better understanding of how IV's work, but still have some confusion.
So Stamina IV directly relates to HP. but what about Attack and Defense ? Let's say you have two pokemons with identical CP. They have equal Defense IV, but one has a Attack IV bonus of 3 and the other has an Attack IV bonus of 14. How does that impact what each one can do in combat? Obviously the one with Attack IV bonus of 14 is better, but how (quantitatively)? The damage is set by the moveset, so what can it do better than the other?
Same about the Defense IV? If the Stamina and Attack are the same, but one has a lower Defense IV bonus than the other, what does that really translate to in combat numbers?
And how does CP (or pokemon level) affect actual damage? A 150CP Vaporeon with hydropump still dishes out the same 90 damage as a 2800CP Vaporeon, doesn't it? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You assumed two things incorrectly (no wonders, everyone did).

1. The attack stat of the attacker and the defense stat of the defender **do** influence the damage.
2. The levels of the attacker and defender **do** influence the damage.

Let's start with the first one. The [damage formula](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/damage-mechanics) is following:

> Floor(1/2 ∗ Power ∗ Atk/Def ∗ STAB ∗ Effective) + 1

So, here you can see, that Attack and Defense influence the damage output. If attacker with attack X attacks a defender with defense X **on the same level** (we'll get to it later) and if there is no STAB or effectiveness bonus, then it deals half the listed move power plus one (e.g. 90/2 + 1 = 46 damage for Hydro Pump). You can also see the impact of having different attack/defense values. If attacker has attack twice as big as defense, it deals roughly full damage (plus one), on the other hand, if defender had twice as big defense than attack, then only a quarter of the damage is dealt (floored, plus one).

And how levels affect the formula? I omitted one important thing in the formula above. The attack and defense stats used there are not the base stats. There is one more calculation required for each stat:

> Attack = (BaseAttack + AttackIV) ∗ CpM
>
> Defense = (BaseDefense + DefenseIV) ∗ CpM
>
> HP = Floor((BaseStamina + StaminaIV) ∗ CpM)

And this `CpM` is a [value dependent on the level](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/cp-multiplier). CpM for level 1 is 0.094, while CpM for level 30 is 0.7317 and CpM for level 40 is 0.7903. So while it's true, that the base stats never change (Vaporeon level 1 would have same stats as Vaporeon level 40, if they have same IV), their effective attack, defense and hp increase with levels. Thus, if you get your Pokémon from level 1 to level 30, you increase his Attack, Defense and Hp roughly 7.78 times (8.41 times for level 40).

Finally, CP is just an indicator of how "strong" a Pokémon is. In short, it is when you combine level and stats (while you count attack twice) and come up with a number. You can check the exact formula [here](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/pokemon-stats-advanced).